# error referenced from:

Tags: c++, build

Given the definition of a function that prints out on the screen the remaining two edges of a rectangle when two edges are given as arguments :

```
static void restPuncte (Punct &x, Punct &y);
```

and its implementation:

```
void restPuncte (Punct &x, Punct &y)
{
    Punct c;
    c.MutaX(x.GetX());
    c.MutaY(y.GetY());

    Punct d;
    d.MutaX(y.GetX());
    d.MutaY(x.GetY());

    std::cout << "Punctul C este:" << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Punctul D este:" << d << std::endl;
}
```

in main I get the following error when trying to build the project:

```
"Punct::restPuncte(Punct&, Punct&)", referenced from:
```

The main would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "punct.h"

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    Punct firstPoint(1,2);

    Punct thirdPoint(4,3);

    cout << "Determinarea celorlalte doua colturi" << endl;
    cout << "Cele doua puncte sunt:" << firstPoint << " si " << thirdPoint <<endl;
    Punct::restPuncte(firstPoint,thirdPoint);


    return 0;
}
```

Could you please tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: What's the rest of the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void restPuncte (Punct &x, Punct &y)
```

is not the same as

```
void Punct::restPuncte (Punct &x, Punct &y)
```

You're defining a free function, and your `static` method remains undefined.